# Highchart styling issue. Chart doesn't show up as it is coded

Tags: javascript, css, svg, highcharts

I use Highchart library and I ran into an issue. It is about styling.

As default, a chart does not show up as it should be. However, it shows up in a proper position after changing a browser's window.

1) As default 
[image]

A half of chard is covered by the SVG image below.

2) After changing browser's window 
[image]

A chart is started to show as it should be.

I'm wondering if this issue is related to loading Highchart on the browser?

[edit]
HTML and CSS for highchart container

```
<div id="4c9520e8-bac6-46de-a42a-77e91d62cff3" class="donut-chart" data-highcharts-chart="0”>
<div id="highcharts-gwjcais-0" class="highcharts-container " style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; width: 91px; height: 100px; text-align: left; line-height: normal; z-index: 0; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);”>
<svg version="1.1" class="highcharts-root" style="font-family:&quot;Lucida Grande&quot;, &quot;Lucida Sans Unicode&quot;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="91" height="100" viewBox="0 0 91 100"><desc>Created with Highcharts 5.0.14</desc><defs>
<clipPath id="highcharts-gwjcais-1”>
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="71" height="75" fill="none"></rect>
</clipPath></defs>
    <rect fill="none" class="highcharts-background" x="0" y="0" width="91" height="100" rx="0" ry="0"></rect>
    <rect fill="none" class="highcharts-plot-background" x="10" y="10" width="71" height="75"></rect><rect fill="none" class="highcharts-plot-border" x="10" y="10" width="71" height="75"></rect>
    <g class="highcharts-series-group"><g class="highcharts-series highcharts-series-0 highcharts-pie-series highcharts-color-undefined highcharts-tracker " transform="translate(10,10) scale(1 1)”>
    <path fill="rgb(238,56,42)" d="M 35.491018011717046 -6.59999908530483 A 44.1 44.1 0 0 1 74.1590282722946 58.72002669748383 L 70.29312544506514 56.59802402773545 A 39.69 39.69 0 0 0 35.49191621054534 -2.189999176774343 Z" transform="translate(0,0)" stroke="rgb(255,255,255)" stroke-width="1" stroke-linejoin="round" class="highcharts-point highcharts-color-0"></path>
    <path fill="rgb(234,234,234)" d="M 74.13778891962127 58.75867510930048 A 44.1 44.1 0 1 1 35.43874598473104 -6.5999574596803185 L 35.44487138625794 -2.189961713712286 A 39.69 39.69 0 1 0 70.27401002765913 56.632807598370434 Z" transform="translate(0,0)" stroke="rgb(255,255,255)" stroke-width="1" stroke-linejoin="round" class="highcharts-point highcharts-color-1"></path></g>
 <g class="highcharts-markers highcharts-series-0 highcharts-pie-series highcharts-color-undefined " transform="translate(10,10) scale(1 1)"></g></g>
 <g class="highcharts-legend"><rect fill="none" class="highcharts-legend-box" rx="0" ry="0" x="0" y="0" width="8" height="8" visibility="hidden"></rect><g><g></g></g></g></svg>
 <span style="font-family: &quot;Lucida Grande&quot;, &quot;Lucida Sans Unicode&quot;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; position: absolute; white-space: nowrap; margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px; left: 22px; top: 45px; color: rgb(51, 51, 51);" class="highcharts-title" transform="translate(0,0)”>
     <em class="active">1</em>
     <em class="disabled">/3</em>
 </span>
 </div>
 </div> 


.highcharts-container {
margin-top: -80px!important;
width: 200px;
height: 200px!important;
}
```

Comment: It's because of the positioning of your containers. And we cannot say much further without any html and css.

Comment: I added css. I added positioning using margin.

Comment: Please add a [mcve] to the question

Comment: @aaayumi And just from that CSS how do you expect us to tell anything? Whether the svg positioning is affecting it or at what offset it is located at? Provide the complete html and css which produces that output above.

Comment: sorry, I added HTML for reference. In the end, I could manage to fix it by tweaking CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that `margin` was causing positioning issue after tweaking CSS. I set up 'height' for main component (`.donut-chart`) and it started to work fine.

I also replaced `margin-top` in container with `top`.

```
 .donut-chart {
  height: 100px;

  .highcharts-container {
    top: -20px !important;
    width: 200px;

    rect {
      width: 0;
    }
  }

  .highcharts-title {
    margin-top: -15px !important;
  }

}
}
```